# How to update BigDecimal field with mongo scala driver 2.0?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java-driver, mongo-scala-driver

I'm using official `mongo-scala-driver 2.0.0`. And try update field with `BigDecimal` value:

```
myCollection.findOneAndUpdate(
  equal("_id", "someId"),
  set("money", BigDecimal(100.0))
).headResult()
```

And it give's me:

> org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find
>   a codec for class scala.math.BigDecimal

But insertion accepts `BigDecimal`:

```
  myCollection
      .insertOne(
        Document("_id" -> "someId", "money" -> BigDecimal(100.0))
      ).headResult()
```

What is correct way to update BigDecimal field? Is that correct, that insertion supports codec, but update - not

Comment: had the same problem. This one solution helped me:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45053457/how-to-create-decimal128-field-with-inc-operator-in-java-scala