# How to create Decimal128 field with inc operator in java/scala

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java, mongo-java-driver, mongo-scala-driver

I have following document structure:

```
{
    "moneys": {
      "someKey": NumberDecimal(99)
      ...
      "someOtherRandomKey": NumberDecimal(99)
    }
{
```

**What I want**: When nonexistent field increments, create that field with
`NumberDecimal` value.

I tried it with scala driver but cant do that:

```
//not compiles
collection.findOneAndUpdate(filters,Updates.inc("someOtherKey", new Decimal128(50)))
```

because `Updates.inc(k,v)` requires `Number`;  `Decimal128` is not `Number`

I think problem not in driver, but with my logic.

How can I implement my case with scala/java driver?

Comment: When you tried with Scala, how did you import Decimal128? For me is just unrecognized by the language :/

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira I had no problem with it. Try specify full reference without import.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved by implementing codec for `scala.math.BigDecimal`:

```
class BigDecimalScalaCodec extends Codec[scala.math.BigDecimal] {

  override def encode(writer: BsonWriter, value: scala.math.BigDecimal, encoderContext: EncoderContext): Unit = {
    writer.writeDecimal128(new Decimal128(value.bigDecimal))
  }

  override def getEncoderClass: Class[scala.math.BigDecimal] = classOf[scala.math.BigDecimal]

  override def decode(reader: BsonReader, decoderContext: DecoderContext): scala.math.BigDecimal = {
    reader.readDecimal128().bigDecimalValue()
  }
}
```

Register in mongo:

```
 val codecRegistry = fromRegistries(fromCodecs(new BigDecimalScalaCodec()), DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY)

 val database: MongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("dbName")
    .withCodecRegistry(codecRegistry)
```

And now we can use `scala.math.BigDecimal`:

```
collection.findOneAndUpdate(filters,Updates.inc("someOtherKey", BigDecimal(99))
```